# Laravel sends password reset emails with huge delay

Tags: laravel, email

When I submit request for sending password reset email on my website, the email comes to my gmail inbox after almost an hour. I asked from my mail service provider and they said nothing's wrong with their services.
Is there any default delay on sending emails in Laravel?

Comment: just check with https://mailtrap.io if same delay....  then you have to check your code

Comment: Have you checked `Received:` headers of the message?  It should show which server to server hop created the delay.

Comment: I changed MAIL_PORT to 25 and email received immediately! Can I use this port?

Comment: Is that alright?

Comment: Yes it should be alright.